# Choosing the best and more useful method in RCT psychology studies

Tags: repeated-measures, post-hoc, ancova, random-allocation, mancova

I'm not sure had anyone open this question but I'd like to your opinions. When we compare two groups(control&treatment) measured at pre,post and a follow up procedure, which is the most useful tool to say treatment condition superior at post and follow up level? As far as I can see, we can use two way Repeated Measures ANOVA, or ANCOVA with raw scores and change scores. When we compare these, they suggesting ANCOVA mostly. Like in here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266376144_Baseline_adjustment_for_statistical_efficiency_on_clinical_controlled_trial

But I really need an outside opinion in this regard. Could you tell me why ANCOVA is considered best method when we compare groups? Why not just use repeated measures ANOVA interaction section?